I Have Batch class but it does't excute and don't know why i should loop inside it over pages of products and should create batch for every list?
I'm currently working on integrating Shopify products into Salesforce using a batch job. While implementing the batch class, I encountered some challenges that I hope to get your insights on. Here are the details:
I have a batch class, ShopifyProductsBatch, that:

Fetches product data from Shopify using their GraphQL API
Inserts the data into Salesforce
Handles pagination by chaining additional batches if more pages are available.

While testing the batch job, it processes only the first page of products (e.g., 50 records) and doesn’t fetch subsequent pages as expected. Additionally, when I attempt to debug the batch job using the Developer Console, the expected data processing doesn’t seem to occur.
The ShopifyProductsBatch class should handle pagination by chaining itself with the next cursor. However, only the first batch is executed, and subsequent batches are not triggered. So I appreciate if you could help Or tell me where the problem lies?
public static String productQuery(String cursor){
        String query = 'query GetAllProducts($cursor: String) { ' +
        '  products(first: 70, after: $cursor) { ' +
        '    edges { ' +
        '      cursor ' +
        '      node { ' +
        '        id ' +
        '        title ' +
        '        bodyHtml ' +
        '        vendor ' +
        '        productType ' +
        '        handle ' +
        '        publishedAt ' +
        '        tags ' +
        '        status ' +
        '        description ' +
        '        totalInventory '+
        '        variants(first: 20) { ' +
        '          edges { ' +
        '            node { ' +
        '              id ' +
        '              title ' +
        '              price ' +
        '              sku ' +
        '              inventoryQuantity ' +
        '              barcode ' +
        '              taxable ' +
        '              selectedOptions{'+
        '              name'+
        '              value'+
        '              }'+
        '            } ' +
        '          } ' +
        '        } ' +
        '        options { ' +
        '          id ' +
        '          name ' +
        '          values ' +
        '        } ' +
        '        images(first: 20) { ' +
        '          edges { ' +
        '            node { ' +
        '              id ' +
        '              src ' +
        '              width ' +
        '              height ' +
        '            } ' +
        '          } ' +
        '        } ' +
        '      } ' +
        '    } ' +
        '    pageInfo { ' +
        '      hasNextPage ' +
        '      endCursor ' +
        '    } ' +
        '  } ' +
        '}';
        return query ;
    }

public with sharing class ShopifyProductsIntegration {
    //@future(callout=true)
    public static void fetchShopifyProducts(String cursor) {
        List<ShopifyProductWrapper> productWrappers = new List<ShopifyProductWrapper>();
        try {
                Map<String, Object> data = GetData(cursor);
                List<Object> edges = (List<Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) data.get('products')).get('edges');

                for (Object edge : edges) {
                    Map<String, Object> node = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) edge).get('node');

                    ShopifyProductWrapper product = new ShopifyProductWrapper();
                    product.id = (String) node.get('id');
                    product.title = (String) node.get('title');
                    product.bodyHtml = (String) node.get('bodyHtml');
                    product.vendor = (String) node.get('vendor');
                    product.productType = (String) node.get('productType');
                    product.handle = (String) node.get('handle');
                    product.publishedAt = node.containsKey('publishedAt') && node.get('publishedAt') != null 
                        ? Date.valueOf((String) node.get('publishedAt')) 
                        : null;
                    product.description = (String) node.get('description');
                    product.totalInventory = (Integer) node.get('totalInventory');
                    
                    List<Object> tagsList = (List<Object>)node.get('tags');
                    product.tag = new List<String>();
                    for (Object tag : tagsList) {
                        product.tag.add((String)tag);
                    }

                    product.status = (String) node.get('status');
                    
                  // Map Variants
                  product.variants = new List<ShopifyProductWrapper.Variant>();
                  Map<String, Object> variantsData = (Map<String, Object>) node.get('variants');
                  List<Object> variants = (List<Object>) variantsData.get('edges');
                  for (Object variantVar : variants) {
                      Map<String, Object> variantNode = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) variantVar).get('node');
                      ShopifyProductWrapper.Variant variant = new ShopifyProductWrapper.Variant();
                      variant.id = (String) variantNode.get('id');
                      variant.title = (String) variantNode.get('title');
                      variant.price = variantNode.get('price') != null ? Decimal.valueOf((String) variantNode.get('price')) : null;
                      variant.sku = (String) variantNode.get('sku');
                      variant.taxable = variantNode.get('taxable') != null ? (Boolean) variantNode.get('taxable') : null;
                      variant.barcode = (String) variantNode.get('barcode');
                      variant.productId = product.id;
                      variant.inventoryQuantity = variantNode.get('inventoryQuantity') != null ? (Integer) variantNode.get('inventoryQuantity') : null;
                      variant.selectedOptions = new List<ShopifyProductWrapper.SelectedOption>();
                      if (variantNode.get('selectedOptions') != null) {
                          List<Object> selectedOptionsData = (List<Object>) variantNode.get('selectedOptions');
                          
                          for (Object selectedOptionVar : selectedOptionsData) {
                              // Cast each object to a map
                              Map<String, Object> selectedOptionMap = (Map<String, Object>) selectedOptionVar;
                              
                              // Create a new SelectedOption instance
                              ShopifyProductWrapper.SelectedOption selectedOption = new ShopifyProductWrapper.SelectedOption();
                              selectedOption.name = (String) selectedOptionMap.get('name');
                              selectedOption.value = (String) selectedOptionMap.get('value');
                              selectedOption.variantId = variant.id;
                              
                              // Add to the selectedOptions list
                              variant.selectedOptions.add(selectedOption);
                          }
                      }
                      
                      product.variants.add(variant);
                  }
                  // Map Options
                  product.options = new List<ShopifyProductWrapper.Option>() ;
                  List<Object> optionsData = (List<Object>) node.get('options');
                  for (Object optionVar : optionsData) {
                      Map<String, Object> optionMap = (Map<String, Object>)optionVar;
                      ShopifyProductWrapper.Option option = new ShopifyProductWrapper.Option();
                      option.id = (String) optionMap.get('id');
                      option.name = (String) optionMap.get('name');
                      option.productId = product.id;
                      List<Object> valuesList = (List<Object>) optionMap.get('values');
                      List<String> valuesStringList = new List<String>();
                      for (Object value : valuesList) {
                          valuesStringList.add((String)value); // Explicitly cast each value to String
                      }
                      option.values = valuesStringList;
                      product.Options.add(option);
                  }
                  // Map Images
                  product.images = new List<ShopifyProductWrapper.Image>();
                  Map<String, Object> imagesData = (Map<String, Object>) node.get('images');
                  List<Object> images = (List<Object>) imagesData.get('edges');
                  for (Object imageVar : images) {
                      Map<String, Object> imageNode = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) imageVar).get('node');
                      ShopifyProductWrapper.Image image = new ShopifyProductWrapper.Image();
                      image.id = (String) imageNode.get('id');
                      image.src = (String) imageNode.get('src');
                      image.productId = product.id;
                      image.width = imageNode.get('width') != null ? (Integer) imageNode.get('width') : null;
                      image.height = imageNode.get('height') != null ? (Integer) imageNode.get('height') : null;
                      product.Images.add(image);
                  }

                    productWrappers.add(product);
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error fetching Shopify products: ' + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
         ProductValidateAndInsert.insertProduct(productWrappers);
    }

    private static Boolean hasNextPage;
    private static String endCursor;

    public static void setLastPageInfo(Boolean nextPage, String cursor) {
        hasNextPage = nextPage;
        endCursor = cursor;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> getLastPageInfo() {
        return new Map<String, Object>{
            'hasNextPage' => hasNextPage,
            'endCursor' => endCursor
        };
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> GetData(String cursor){
       try{
        String apiToken = ShopifyAuthentication.getApiTokenValue();
        String endpoint = ShopifyAuthentication.getGraphQLEndpoint();
        String tokenName = ShopifyAuthentication.getApiTokenName();
        Map<String, Object> result;
        Map<String, Object> data;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String query = GraphQLQueries.productQuery(cursor);
        Map<String, Object> variables = new Map<String, Object>{
            'cursor' => cursor
        };
        Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>{
            'query' => query,
            'variables' => variables
        };
        
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader(tokenName, apiToken);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setBody(JSON.serialize(payload));
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) 
            {
                result = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                data = (Map<String, Object>) result.get('data');
                Map<String, Object> pageInfo = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) data.get('products')).get('pageInfo');
                setLastPageInfo((Boolean) pageInfo.get('hasNextPage'), (String) pageInfo.get('endCursor'));
            }
            else {
                throw new CustomException('Failed to fetch Shopify products: ' + response.getBody());
            }
            return data;
       }
       catch(Exception e){
   throw new CustomException('Failed to fetch Shopify products: ' + e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}

public with sharing class ProductValidateAndInsert {

    public static void insertProduct(List<ShopifyProductWrapper> shopifyProducts) {
        if (shopifyProducts == null || shopifyProducts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomException('No Shopify products provided for insertion.');
        }

        List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>();
        List<Variant__c> variants = new List<Variant__c>();
        List<Option__c> options = new List<Option__c>();
        List<Selected_Option__c> selectedOptions = new List<Selected_Option__c>();
        List<ContentVersion> images = new List<ContentVersion>();
        Map<String, Account> accountTagsMap;
        
        try {
            accountTagsMap = getAccountTags();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error fetching account tags: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }

        Set<String> existingVariantIds;
        try {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Variant__c.isAccessible()) {
                throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to access Variant__c records');
            }
            existingVariantIds = new Set<String>();
            for (Variant__c variant : [SELECT Shopify_Id__c FROM Variant__c]) {
                existingVariantIds.add(variant.Shopify_Id__c);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error querying existing variants: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            for (ShopifyProductWrapper product : shopifyProducts) {
                String matchingTags = getMatchingTag(product.tag, accountTagsMap);
                Product2 prod = new Product2();
                    // Prepare Product2 object
                    prod.Name = product.title;
                    prod.Total_Inventory__c = product.totalInventory;
                if (!String.isBlank(matchingTags)) {
                    Account vendorAccount = accountTagsMap.get(matchingTags);
                    if (vendorAccount != null) {
                        prod.Status__c = 'Verified';
                        prod.IsActive = true;
                        prod.Vendor__c = vendorAccount.Id;
                    }
                } else {
                    prod.Status__c = 'Unverified';
                    prod.IsActive = false;
                }
                products.add(prod);

                // Prepare Variants
                for (ShopifyProductWrapper.Variant variantNode : product.variants) {
                    Variant__c variant = new Variant__c();
                    variant.Shopify_Id__c = variantNode.id;

                    // Add Selected Options for new Variants
                    if (!existingVariantIds.contains(variantNode.id)) {
                        for (ShopifyProductWrapper.SelectedOption selectedOption : variantNode.selectedOptions) {
                            Selected_Option__c option = new Selected_Option__c();
                            option.Name = selectedOption.name;
                            option.Variant__r = new Variant__c(Shopify_Id__c = variantNode.id);
                            selectedOptions.add(option);
                        }
                    }

                    variants.add(variant);
                }
                getImagesData(shopifyProducts);
                // Prepare Options
                for (ShopifyProductWrapper.Option optionNode : product.options) {
                    Option__c option = new Option__c();
                    options.add(option);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error processing Shopify products: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (!products.isEmpty()) {
                if (!Schema.sObjectType.Product2.isUpdateable() || !Schema.sObjectType.Product2.isCreateable()) {
                    throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to upsert Product2 records');
                }
                upsert products Shopify_Id__c;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error inserting/upserting products: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (!variants.isEmpty()) {
                if (!Schema.sObjectType.Variant__c.isUpdateable() || !Schema.sObjectType.Variant__c.isCreateable()) {
                    throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to upsert Variant__c records');
                }
                upsert variants Shopify_Id__c;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error inserting/upserting variants: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (!selectedOptions.isEmpty()) {
                if (!Schema.sObjectType.Selected_Option__c.isCreateable()) {
                    throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to create Selected_Option__c records');
                }
                insert selectedOptions;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error inserting selected options: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (!options.isEmpty()) {
                if (!Schema.sObjectType.Option__c.isUpdateable() || !Schema.sObjectType.Option__c.isCreateable()) {
                    throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to upsert Option__c records');
                }
                upsert options Shopify_Id__c;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error inserting/upserting options: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Account> getAccountTags() {
        Map<String, Account> accountTagsMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        try {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.isAccessible()) {
                throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to access Account records');
            }
            for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, Tag__c FROM Account WHERE Tag__c != null]) {
                accountTagsMap.put(acc.Tag__c, acc);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error querying accounts for tags: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return accountTagsMap;
    }

    private static String getMatchingTag(List<String> productTags, Map<String, Account> accountTagsMap) {
        String matchingTag = '';
        try {
            if (productTags != null) {
                for (String tag : productTags) {
                    if (accountTagsMap.containsKey(tag.trim())) {
                        matchingTag = tag.trim();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error matching tags: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return matchingTag;
    }

    public static void getImagesData(List<ShopifyProductWrapper> shopifyProducts){
    try {
        if (!Schema.sObjectType.Product2.isAccessible() || !Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isAccessible()) {
            throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to access records');
        }
        
        // Collect product IDs and query existing products
        Set<String> shopifyProductIds = new Set<String>();
        for(ShopifyProductWrapper product : shopifyProducts) {
            shopifyProductIds.add(product.id);
        }
        
        Map<String, Id> shopifyToSalesforceIds = new Map<String, Id>();
        for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Shopify_Id__c FROM Product2 WHERE Shopify_Id__c IN :shopifyProductIds]) {
            shopifyToSalesforceIds.put(p.Shopify_Id__c, p.Id);
        }
        
        // Prepare data for async processing
        Set<String> imageIds = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, String> imageSrcMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> imageTitleMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, Id> productIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
        
        for (ShopifyProductWrapper product : shopifyProducts) {
            Id sfProductId = shopifyToSalesforceIds.get(product.id);
            if (sfProductId != null) {
                for (ShopifyProductWrapper.Image imageNode : product.images) {
                    imageIds.add(imageNode.id);
                    imageSrcMap.put(imageNode.id, imageNode.src);
                    imageTitleMap.put(imageNode.id, product.title + '_' + imageNode.id);
                    productIdMap.put(imageNode.id, sfProductId);
                }
            }
        }
        Map<String, Object> dataToPass = new Map<String, Object>{
            'imageIds' => imageIds,
            'imageSrcMap' => imageSrcMap,
            'imageTitleMap' => imageTitleMap,
            'productIdMap' => productIdMap
        };
        String serializedData = JSON.serialize(dataToPass);
        
        processImagesAsync(serializedData);
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new CustomException('Error preparing images: ' + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

   @future(callout=true)
    public static void processImagesAsync(String serializedData) {
        try {
            System.debug('Future method called with serializedData: ' + serializedData);
    
            // Deserialize the data
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(serializedData);
    
            // Safely cast the imageIds list to Set<String>
            List<Object> rawImageIds = (List<Object>) data.get('imageIds');
            Set<String> imageIds = new Set<String>();
            if (rawImageIds != null) {
                for (Object obj : rawImageIds) {
                    if (obj != null) {
                        imageIds.add((String) obj);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            // Safely cast other maps
            Map<String, String> imageSrcMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Map<String, String> imageTitleMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Map<String, Id> productIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    
            // Cast Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String> for imageSrcMap
            Map<String, Object> rawImageSrcMap = (Map<String, Object>) data.get('imageSrcMap');
            if (rawImageSrcMap != null) {
                for (String key : rawImageSrcMap.keySet()) {
                    imageSrcMap.put(key, (String) rawImageSrcMap.get(key));
                }
            }
    
            // Cast Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String> for imageTitleMap
            Map<String, Object> rawImageTitleMap = (Map<String, Object>) data.get('imageTitleMap');
            if (rawImageTitleMap != null) {
                for (String key : rawImageTitleMap.keySet()) {
                    imageTitleMap.put(key, (String) rawImageTitleMap.get(key));
                }
            }
    
            // Cast Map<String, Object> to Map<String, Id> for productIdMap
            Map<String, Object> rawProductIdMap = (Map<String, Object>) data.get('productIdMap');
            if (rawProductIdMap != null) {
                for (String key : rawProductIdMap.keySet()) {
                    productIdMap.put(key, (Id) rawProductIdMap.get(key));
                }
            }
    
            // Processing images
            List<ContentVersion> images = new List<ContentVersion>();
            Map<String, Id> existingContentVersions = new Map<String, Id>();
    
            // Add CRUD check before query
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isAccessible()) {
                throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to access ContentVersion object');
            }
    
            for (ContentVersion cv : [
                SELECT Shopify_Id__c, Id 
                FROM ContentVersion 
                WHERE Shopify_Id__c IN :imageIds
            ]) {
                existingContentVersions.put(cv.Shopify_Id__c, cv.Id);
            }
    
            for (String imageId : imageIds) {
                try {
                    if (existingContentVersions.containsKey(imageId)) {
                        continue;
                    }
    
                    ContentVersion image = new ContentVersion();
                    image.Shopify_Id__c = imageId;
                    image.Title = imageTitleMap.get(imageId);
                    image.PathOnClient = imageTitleMap.get(imageId) + '.jpg';
    
                    String imageSrc = imageSrcMap.get(imageId);
                    if (!String.isEmpty(imageSrc) && !imageSrc.startsWith('data:image')) {
                        // Fetch the image from URL
                        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                        req.setEndpoint(imageSrc);
                        req.setMethod('GET');
                        Http http = new Http();
                        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    
                        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                            image.VersionData = res.getBodyAsBlob();
                        } else {
                            throw new CustomException('Failed to download image: ' + imageSrc);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Decode Base64
                        image.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(imageSrc);
                    }
    
                    // Associate with product
                    Id productId = productIdMap.get(imageId);
                    if (productId != null) {
                        image.FirstPublishLocationId = productId;
                    } else {
                        throw new CustomException('No matching product found for image ID: ' + imageId);
                    }
    
                    images.add(image);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new CustomException('Error processing image ID ' + imageId + ': ' + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
    
            // Insert images
            if (!images.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    if (!Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isCreateable()) {
                        throw new CustomException('Insufficient permissions to create ContentVersion records');
                    }
                    insert images;
                    System.debug('Inserted images: ' + images);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new CustomException('Error inserting images: ' + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomException('Error in processImagesAsync: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class ShopifyProductsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private String cursor;

    // Constructor to initialize the cursor
    public ShopifyProductsBatch(String cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    // Start method: Fetch the first set of products
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]);
    }


    // Execute method: Process each batch of products
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> scope) {
        try {

            // Call Shopify API
            ShopifyProductsIntegration.fetchShopifyProducts(cursor);

            // Process fetched products after the callout
            // if (!productWrappers.isEmpty()) {
            //     // Process products after callout (e.g., validation and insertion)
            //    ProductValidateAndInsert.insertProduct(productWrappers);
                System.debug('Products Fetched Successfully');
            // }

            // Get pagination info
            Map<String, Object> lastPageInfo = ShopifyProductsIntegration.getLastPageInfo();
            Boolean hasNextPage = (Boolean) lastPageInfo.get('hasNextPage');
            cursor = (String) lastPageInfo.get('endCursor');
            System.debug('Has Next Page: ' + hasNextPage + ', Next Cursor: ' + cursor);

            // Schedule next batch if more pages exist
            if (hasNextPage) {
                System.scheduleBatch(new ShopifyProductsBatch(cursor), 'Next Shopify Batch', 1);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error in Batch Execute: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // Finish method: Perform cleanup or log actions
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        System.debug('Batch processing completed!');
    }
}


This should've been an edit to your original question, but oh well, guess we'll use this one.

Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your post to describe the basic troubleshooting you have done.  What did you see in the debug logs?  Please [edit] your post to add this information.

Get rid of the try/catch. An empty catch block is just shooting yourself in the foot. Debug statements don't count as non-empty.

a) way too much code dumped here; reduce to minimum needed to understand the issue; b) doing scheduleBatch in the middle of execute() is an odd pattern; should be done in finish()

Thanks for your advice i fixed it

What do you mean "you fixed it"? If you resolved your issue, please either apply the changes to the question outlined in the previous comments and then post a self-answer explaining what you corrected or delete the question.
